# How can you check the amount in your blockchain or bitcoin address online?

Tags: blockchain

How can know or check your blockchain or bitcoin account address to know amount on it?

Comment: Just to be clear, are you asking about how to see if you own any bitcoin on the bitcoin blockchain, or are you asking about the company "Blockchain.info"?  The term "account" is often misused when talking about Bitcoin, so it's difficult to tell what people mean when using it.

Answer (score 1):

You can look up an address on a block explorer such as http://blockchain.info.  Just paste the address into the search box, and you will see a list of all transactions going in and out of that address, and its current balance.